# Upper bound of the integral $\int_\delta^\infty t^m e^{-\nu t^2} dt$

Tags: inequality, improper-integrals, bounds-of-integration

I am reading Wong's book on "Asymptotic Approximations of Integrals". On page 497, the book recalls (without proof) the following estimate: for all $\delta>0$ and $\nu>1$,
$$
\int_\delta^\infty t^m e^{-\nu t^2} dt \le K_\delta e^{-\nu \delta^2},
$$
where $K_\delta$ is a constant independent of $\nu$.

May I know whether the above estimate  is a well-known result? Could you provide a reference for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can proceed by induction on $m$. Integrating by parts with $t^{m-1}$ and $te^{-νt^2}$ we get
$$\int_δ^\infty t^m e^{-νt^2} dt = \left[\frac{-1}{2ν} t^{m-1} e^{-νt^2}\right]_δ^\infty + \frac{m-1}{2ν}\int_δ^\infty t^{m-2} e^{-νt^2} dt
= \frac{1}{2ν}\left(δ^{m-1}e^{-νt^2} + (m-1)\int_δ^\infty t^{m-2} e^{-νt^2} dt\right).$$
Bounding $\frac{1}{2ν}\leq \frac{1}{2}$ (since $ν>1$) and applying the inductive hypothesis to the remaining integral gives you the result.

Comment: Strictly speaking, to complete the induction argument, one has to verify the bound for $m=0$.

Comment: Yes! I am actually a bit unsure about $m=0$, but $m=1$ works straightforward by substituting $u = -νt^2$.

Comment: The case with $m=0$ can be shown using the upper bound in Equation 7.8.3 in [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.8).

Answer (score 1):

Performing the change of integration variables from $t$ to $s$ via $
t = \delta \sqrt {1 + s}$ gives
$$
\int_\delta ^{ + \infty } {t^m {\rm e}^{ - \nu t^2 } {\rm d}t}  = \frac{{\delta ^{m + 1} }}{2}{\rm e}^{ - \nu \delta ^2 } \int_0^{ + \infty } {(1 + s)^{(m - 1)/2} {\rm e}^{ - \nu \delta ^2 s} {\rm d}s} .
$$
Since $\nu>1$, we can assert that
$$
 \int_0^{ + \infty } {(1 + s)^{(m - 1)/2} {\rm e}^{ - \nu \delta ^2 s} {\rm d}s}  \le  \int_0^{ + \infty } {(1 + s)^{(m - 1)/2} {\rm e}^{ - \delta ^2 s} {\rm d}s} .
$$
Hence, the claim follows by letting
$$
K_\delta   = \frac{{\delta ^{m + 1} }}{2}\int_0^{ + \infty } {(1 + s)^{(m - 1)/2} {\rm e}^{ - \delta ^2 s} {\rm d}s} .
$$